# How can I set the Selected value on a DevExpress LookupEdit?

Tags: devexpress

I previously asked a similar question, but the code was much more complicated.  This question involves a similar problem, but the code is drastically simplified.  Still, even as simple as this example is, I can NOT get the dropdown to pre-select the correct value.

I have a dropdown that is populated w/ values correctly.  Also, when I change the dropdown to any of the values, and then save my form, the database record is updated w/ the correct value.  That much is working, but selecting the correct value on form load will not work.

I put these lines in my save method, just to see what I'm working with.

```
var test1 = _myLookupEdit.EditValue;  //evaluates to 2
var test2 = _myLookupEdit.Properties.KeyValue;  //evaluates to 2
```

However, when I set either of these during form load, nothing happens; the dropdown has a blank entry selected (and the rest of the values are seen when you expand the dropdown).  I've tried each of these methods:

```
_myLookupEdit.EditValue = 2;
_myLookupEdit.Properties.KeyValue = 2;
```

Edit - I posted a comment below under platon's answer, but I'll post it here as well.  I eventually used a stored procedure instead to populate this dropdown, instead of an Enum.  From that point on, the dropdown loaded w/ the correct selected value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the editor's EditValue property to a value according to the type of the editor's Properties.ValueMember field type.  I mean, if this is a string field, the EditValue should be set to "2", not 2 and so on.  This should help.  If not, please try to call the editor's Properties.ForceInitialize() method after you've set the editor's DataSource property.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that had zero effect, but I do appreciate the help.

Comment: I changed my project to populate w/ a stored proc, instead of an Enum.  Bounty goes to platon for the effort.

Comment: Actually platon's solution did work for me (DevExpress 13.2.9) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Platon, fixed the issues I was having!